# Most elegant way to assign multiple variables to the same value?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

This question may already been asked but I couldn't find a proper way to assign multiple variables to one value without linking them to it, so bear with me.

**Example 1:**

```
a = b = []
a.append('x')
> a = ['x']
> b = ['x']
```

Since I append `'x'` to `a` I don't want to have it in `b`.

---

**Example 2:**

```
a, b = [[], []]
a.append('x')
> a = ['x']
> b = []
```

Works as expected but with multiple variables it becomes really ugly:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i j = [[], [], [], [], [], [], ...]
```

---

**Example 3:**

The default way

```
a = []
b = []
...
```

Same as example 2, it's not pretty with multiple variables.

I was wondering if something like this exists like in javascript?

```
a, b, c = [] #this actually gives a ValueError: not enough values to unpack
```

Any suggestions or am I limited to this?

*Note: for some reason I have to avoid using dictionaries for this task. (limitation...)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest you use fewer independent variables first and foremost. Any code that literally has `a, b, c, d, e, ...` in it should be refactored to something simpler.

Having said that:

```
a, b, c = ([] for _ in range(3))
```

The generator creates a new `[]` for as many items as you specify in the `range`.

Comment: `a, b, c = [[] for _ in range(3)]` is also another way of achieving it.

Comment: Agreed, unfortunately I'm working on a legacy code with a few restrictions.

Comment: @Bazingaa That's more inefficient though, as it creates a useless intermediate list.

Comment: Hmm, right. Although for 3 variables, it won't matter. But yeah

Answer (score 0):

For a variable number of connected variables, a dictionary is one recommended solution. You can use a dictionary comprehension to ensure that list values are not linked.

If your variables are genuinely letters, you can also utilize `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

d = {i: [] for i in ascii_lowercase[:10]}
d['a'].append(1)

print(d)

{'a': [1], 'b': [], 'c': [], 'd': [], 'e': [],
 'f': [], 'g': [], 'h': [], 'i': [], 'j': []}
```

In contrast, and for reference, note that using `dict.fromkeys` will ensure that the *same* list is used for each key:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(ascii_lowercase[:10], [])
d['a'].append(1)

print(d)

{'a': [1], 'b': [1], 'c': [1], 'd': [1], 'e': [1],
 'f': [1], 'g': [1], 'h': [1], 'i': [1], 'j': [1]}
```